# Eclipse - maven warning when using parent project resources folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have parent ROOT maven project, it holds resources folder which every child project use using the following lines in pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>../ROOT/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

But it produce a warning

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Access "..\ROOT\resources" directory outside of project base directory. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources) pom.xml /Proudct    line 1  Maven Build Participant Problem

How to avoid such warning? is my setup wrong for sharing resources in child projects? or is it a false positive warning?

Comment: Why are you using a resource from another module? What kind of information are you using there? Why are the resources not in the appropriate module?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have shared resources for multiple projects

Comment: You mean by shared that you need it different modules?

Comment: @khmarbaise I use same configuration/properties files in different modules

Comment: Than make a separate module which contains only the resources folder in default location and define simply a dependency to it where you need it...so you get it on the classpath which solves the problem...

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you give an answer that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to make a separate module which contains only the resources folder. All other modules which need the resources just define a dependency to that new module. The result is that the new module is on the classpath and the resources are accessible.